# Multiple values in database field

Tags: php, arrays

I have a specifications table for some products. Some products come in different colors. So to make that clear it shows some little color boxes.
So I have table field colors which stores colors like this:
black,white,green

I came this far with the code:

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $kleur) {

    $myString = $kleur['kleur'];
    $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
    print_r($myArray);
?>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">Kleur:</td>
        <td>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.ledframes.nl/images/product_details/accessoires/kleuren/<?php echo $myArray[0];?>.jpg"/></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The print_r shows all the values from the field. And if the change the number at echo $myArray[0] it shows the right color boxes in my specifications table.

Now my question is, if the color field has multiple values how do I loop it so it shows all the color blocks?

I read somewhere that you can use something like this:

```
foreach( $array as $name => $key)
```

I have tried to implement this to my code but can't get it to work

Comment: Just use: `foreach ($myArray as $colorName) { <insert code here> }` since your keys are not important, that should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I read somewhere"? When will people finally start reading the documentation of the tools they use before asking? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Yeah thanks, already been on that page and 10 others like that. I'm not posting it here because somebody can shove the answer to me just like that. I'm posting something here because I just can't get it to work. Maybe it's something simple but for me it's kinda diffucult as a newbie....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, $result is the array of database records, and for each record (which you call $kleur), $myArray is the array of color names.

So, to show all the color fields, you need another loop over $myArray, e.g. like this:

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $kleur) {

    $myString = $kleur['kleur'];
    $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
    print_r($myArray);
?>
<tr>
    <td width="20%">Kleur:</td>
    <td>
    <?php
    foreach($myArray as $colorName) {
    ?>
      <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.ledframes.nl/images/product_details/accessoires/kleuren/<?php echo $colorName;?>.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes thank you! This solved my problem. Just missing an extra loop. Thanks, seeing the problem now:)